# Check file distribution across directories

Tags: java, unit-testing

**Background**

I have an application that is creating a number of subfolders in a fixed directory. Across those directories it is putting a number of files. The number of files is equally distributed across those folders. I have a test that checks for a fixed value across the folders, so n files in each folder.

**Question**

How can i test that, where there are 4 subfolders and 5 messages the distribution of messages across those 4 subfolders is 2 messages in 1 folder and 1 message in the other 3?

**Source Code**

```
public boolean checkFileCountInEachFolder(int expectedCount){
    File folder = new File(AppProperties.getInstance().get("path"));
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                int fileCount = listFiles(file, new ArrayList<File>()).size();
                if (fileCount!=expectedCount) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hint regarding your naming: methods with "check" in their name usually do not return booleans. Meaning: either you keep it a "check"; then it should throw an exception to indicate a problem; or you rename it to "doAllFoldersHaveEqualFileCount" or something alike. And if you would rename it to "doAllFoldersHaveLessThanFiles" ... that might give you a hint how to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, here is one of them.

First, list the subdirectories with a `FileFilter` .

Divide the number of messages (the method's parameter being the number of messages) , by the number of folders, to get the minimum expected occurences (may be 0) .

Since you are equally distributing, the max number of occurences can't be more than the min + 1.

Check that the number of files in each subfolder is in this range (or is simply  equal to min or to max, in this particular case).

Finally, sum the count of all files found, and compare the result to the total number of messages .

```
public boolean checkFileCountInEachFolder(final int nbMessages) {

    File folder = new File(AppProperties.getInstance().get("path"));

    File[] subFolders = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(final File f) {
            return f.isDirectory();
        }
    });

    int nbFolders = subFolders.length;
    int minOccurences = nbMessages / nbFolders;
    int maxOccurences = minOccurences + 1;

    int totalCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < subFolders.length; i++) {
        File file = subFolders[i];

        int fileCount = listFiles(file, new ArrayList<File>()).size();
        if (fileCount < minOccurences || fileCount > maxOccurences) {
            return false;
        }

        totalCount += fileCount;

    }

    return (totalCount == nbMessages);

}
```

Comment: should the final line be: return (totalCount == nbMessages);